# extending ec2 reserved instance usage

Tags: amazon-ec2

We bought a reserved instance one year ago. Its up and running now.
Now since its about to expire, I wish to make another one year's payment and continue using it as a reserved instance.
But when I try to 'Purchase Reserved Instances', it does not show any option for current reserved instance.
If I right click on my existing instance, the only option is 'Purchase more like these' ... and not anything regarding extending the current reserved instance.
How can i continue using my existing reserved instance ??

Comment: This topic isn't really relevant to SO.  Probably Serverfault is where it should be.  You just need to make a new 1 year reservation on the day that your current reservation expires and you'll get the reservation pricing.

Comment: You can easily send an email to Amazon support and just request they extend it by a year.

Comment: It does seem odd that you can't extend an instance reservation from the interface.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of EC2 Reserved Instance is not like the concept of server hosting before.

There's no "continue" concept here. You just need to purchase another EC2 Reserved Instance right after your current reserved instance expiration, and AWS will calculate the hourly price with your reserved instance price rate automatically. But do make sure you purchase your new reserved instance with correct parameters (instance size, region, zone...).

Hope this information is helpful for you.

Comment: Invite you to answer this question [How do I upgrade from t2.micro to t2.small at the moment of expiration?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/105863/how-do-i-upgrade-from-t2-micro-to-t2-small-at-the-moment-of-expiration).